# Fetch data from a website and return as a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking to take information from here

http://openexchangerates.org/api/historical/1999-04-12.json?app_id=a9e50249a61b41249e85591d11f22de5

and return the data as a dictionary.
So far I have the code

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://openexchangerates.org/api/historical/1999-04-12.json?app_id=a9e50249a61b41249e85591d11f22de5')
html = response.read().decode("utf-8")
return json.loads(html)
my_dict = json.loads(html)
pprint(my_dict)
```

how can I take just the currency codes and rates without the disclaimer at the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you want is in a dictionary contained within the overall dictionary.  All you have to do is take that specific dictionary entry which is `my_dict['rates']`.  Run the following to see the piece that you are interested in.

```
pprint(my_dict['rates'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get *just* the rates into your `my_dict` variable by simply assigning only that key to the variable:

```
my_dict = json.loads(html)['rates']
```

Now the *only* thing that is in there is the rates. The other keys (`disclaimer`, `license`, `timestamp` and `base`) are not saved at all.

---

Note: You have a `return` in the middle of your code block. If this is in a function, then you will never get to the line where data is assigned to `my_dict`. If it is not in a function, you will get an error. You probably don't want this in the code block at it's current location.

Comment: Good catch on the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary you've created by parsing a JSON string is no different from the dictionaries you've created other ways.  It has all the same methods, and its members can be accessed by subscripting in the usual way.

Looking at the JSON, it's clear that the `"rates"` key contains the mapping from currencies to values, so just use it:

```
rates = my_dict["rates"]
```